# Not sure how to fill out missing paramters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This method is in tutor_session model

```
 def self.tutor_minutes_ranking(users, start_date, end_date)
     joins(:session_users)
     .select('session_users.user_id, SUM(session_length)')
     .where("session_users.user_id IN (?) and tutor_sessions.created_at > ? and tutor_sessions.created_at < ?", users, start_date.to_datetime, end_date.to_datetime)
     .group('session_users.user_id')
     .sum(:session_length, :order => 'sum_session_length DESC')
 end
```

Ok, trying to get the total amount of minutes tutored in a **month**

This method is not written by me.

But I am trying to use it so I can display the total.

This is what I have in a different controller (ie, not tutor_session controller):

```
    @total_minutes_month = TutorSession.total_minutes_for_user(current_user)
```

This is what I have in the view:

```
<% @total_minutes_month.each do |i| %>
   <%= i.first %>
<% end %>
```

This is the error that comes up:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)
```

Obviously I didn't fill out the parameters for the second or third argument as displayed in the method.

The thing is, I'm not sure how to fill out the start_date, and end_date.

Advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for the total time in this month:

```
TutorSession.total_minutes_for_user(current_user, 
                                    Time.now.beginning_of_month, 
                                    Time.now)
```

and something like this for the last month:

```
TutorSession.total_minutes_for_user(current_user, 
                                    1.month.ago.beginning_of_month, 
                                    1.month.ago.end_of_month)
```

Comment: get this error for both of them: `undefined method `each' for 0:Fixnum`

Comment: never mind my previous comment. I was still using each on it, when I shouldn't have been, right? It works, and I do appreciate it. Just wondering, is there another way to fill it out? How do you know about `beginning_of_month` and `end_of_month`?

Comment: The method expects two dates or timestamps. You can use whatever time range you need by using this `Time.parse('2014-04-14 15:45')`

Answer (score 1):

`@spickermann`'s answer is correct to solve your `arguments` error

---

However, when you mention you're then receiving an `undefined_method` error for the `.each` statement - the problem will be caused by `@total_minutes_month` having only the value of `0` - meaning there's no `array`/`hash` to cycle through

If you want to display the data you have from your method as it is now, you'll be best doing something like:

```
#app/views/controller/view.html.erb
<%= @total_minutes_month #-> should display total minutes for user %>
```

I'd personally attach the method to the `user` model's association, so you can call `current_user.tutor_sessions.first.total_minutes_month`:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tutor_sessions, through :session_users do
       def self.tutor_minutes_month(start, end)
           joins(:session_users)
          .select('session_users.user_id, SUM(session_length)')
          .where("session_users.user_id IN (?) and tutor_sessions.created_at > ? and tutor_sessions.created_at < ?", id, start.to_datetime, end.to_datetime)
          .group('session_users.user_id')
          .sum(:session_length, :order => 'sum_session_length DESC')
       end
   end
end
```

Something like this will allow you to call `current_user.tutor_sessions.first.total_minutes_month` to give you the minutes per tutor session

Comment: hey, thanks for explaining why I was receiving `undefined_method` error for `.each` ... appreciate that. The application is not mine to modify. Wait ... just reread your last sentence. What do you mean per tutor session? Sorry, I'm sleepy, so probably not understanding what you're saying, but I was trying to have the total amount of minutes per month, hence my confusion of your last sentence.